# How to append one value from drop-down list to the end of input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to append one value from drop-down list to the end of input box ? 
Hereby am enclosing my Code. I want to append the currency symbol[Whichever is selected in the drop down list ] at the end of Revenue Input box.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Stack query</title>
    <style>

    table{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height:20%;
        width:20%;
        margin: 5%;
    }
    table tr td label, table tr td input,table tr td select {
        width:100%;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Currency">Currency</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="currency" id="currency">
                            <option value="Select" selected disabled="disabled">Select Currency</option>
                            <option value="Dollar">$ USD</option>
                            <option value="Pound">£ GBP</option>
                            <option value="Euro">€ EUR</option>
                            <option value="Yen">¥ YEN</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><label for="Revenue">Revenue</label></td>
                <td><input id="Revenue" type="text" required></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `<span>` tag to display the currency symbol as shown below:

```js
$('#currency').on('change', function() {
  $('#symbol').text(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText.charAt(0));
  // or the jQuery version
  //$('#symbol').text($(this).find('option:selected').text().charAt(0));
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5%;
}
table tr td label,
table tr td input,
table tr td select {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Currency">Currency</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
          <option value="Select" selected disabled="disabled">Select Currency</option>
          <option value="Dollar">$ USD</option>
          <option value="Pound">£ GBP</option>
          <option value="Euro">€ EUR</option>
          <option value="Yen">¥ YEN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Revenue">Revenue</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Revenue" type="text" required>
        <span id="symbol"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

To update the textbox value itself, try something like:

```js
$('#currency').on('change', function() {
  var selected;
  var symbols = $(this.options).map(function(option) {
    if (this.selected)
      selected = this.innerText.charAt(0);
    return this.innerText.charAt(0);
  }).get();
  $('#Revenue').val(function(i, val) {
    if (!val) return
    return symbols.indexOf(val.slice(-1)) >= 0 ?
      val.slice(0, -1) + selected : val + selected;
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5%;
}
table tr td label,
table tr td input,
table tr td select {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Currency">Currency</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
          <option value="Select" selected disabled="disabled">Select Currency</option>
          <option value="Dollar">$ USD</option>
          <option value="Pound">£ GBP</option>
          <option value="Euro">€ EUR</option>
          <option value="Yen">¥ YEN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Revenue">Revenue</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="Revenue" type="text" required>
        <span id="symbol"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working, Thanks. What if i want to append inside the text box ?

Comment: @Yashika that's bit tricky since you need to check if a symbol exists at the end or not, will update the answer in a minute

Comment: @T J - Did you figure out ?

Comment: @Yashika see the update I think I made it more complicated than it should be :)

Comment: Write some code to check whether the Revenue input box is filled or not. and append the sign only then

Comment: @Yashika that's the `val.length > 0` condition in ternary... Can you tell me what's the issue? No need of symbol if text field is empty?

Comment: When i am filling Revenue value after selecting the currency. Its appearing at starting rather than at last. I want it to append it at last not begginning

Comment: @Yashika added a condition to do nothing if input is empty. I think it's better to have it as a separate element. You can adjust the CSS to make it look like part of the input

Comment: Hey T J , I am facing an issue in html coding. But i dont have right to post question . Can you help me with it

Comment: @Yashika What do you mean you don't have right to post question.. what issue are you facing?

Comment: @ T J - I am new here in Stackoverflow and cant post question[as i have reached my limit of asking one question in 6 days]. I want to make "Horizontal and vertical handler" on my Page. By Handler i am refering to JSFIDDLE handler.  If you are not getting me just check this code on coding of any JSFIDDLE page "<div class="handler handler_horizontal" style="top: 249px;"></div>"

Comment: @Yashika You might have a [question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). [You should consider adding more code and explaination to existing questions and improving them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/256148) to lift the ban so that you can ask questions again.

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I was not aware of all this. After your Edit , i earned 5 Reputation. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

```js
$('#currency').on('change', function() {
  $('#toAppend').text(this.value);
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  //height: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5%;
}
table tr td label,
table tr td input,
table tr td select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Currency">Currency</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="currency" id="currency">
          <option value="Select" selected disabled="disabled">Select Currency</option>
          <option value="Dollar">$ USD</option>
          <option value="Pound">£ GBP</option>
          <option value="Euro">€ EUR</option>
          <option value="Yen">¥ YEN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Revenue" id='toAppend'>Revenue</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- Id added -->
        <input id="Revenue" type="text" required>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your is appending the values in sequence. i want -> everytime i select new value, only the selected value get append

Comment: You should clear the existing value of the label `Revenue` before appending the changed value from the dropdown.

Comment: @Yashika Use `$('#Revenue').text('').after(this.value);` in place of the code written above inside the `change` event.